# Mac Pro, Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, mac

Can't rename LV (Logical Volume) Name:

[image]

I cannot change LV Name neither in Finder or via Terminal. The name looks strange, thanks to my 2.5 years daughter. I have no idea how she changed the name, but it happened. If I try to rename simply in Finder, the message is that I should use either smaller number of symbols or avoid using commas et cetera. This message appears even if I try to use a single symbol like 'd' as a new name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing the name in the first place was easy - a 2-year-old could do it ;-) Select HD, hit Enter, lean on keyboard; renaming ends when Enter is hit again, or anything else is clicked on. Random, but easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename it issuing this command on the terminal as a privileged user:

```
diskutil CoreStorage rename (uuid of the logical volume) NewName
```